# How to remove space between section tags

Tags: html, css

I'm having some trouble removing the space between the two sections of my code.

Here is the [JSFiddle of my code](https://jsfiddle.net/kpc1y1s2/).

```css
/********************Intro**********************/

.intro-content {
    padding-top:  250px;
}

.intro-content h1 {
    font-family: "Arial Black";
    font-weight: bolder;
}

#typed {
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.button {
    padding-top: 50px;
}

.button button {
    background-color: black;
    border-color: black;
    border-radius: 25px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bolder;
    margin-bottom: 22%;
}



/********************Intro*********************/



/********************Contact*********************/

#about {
    background-color: lightgray;
}

#skill {
    background-color: lightblue;
}

#intro-section {
    background-color: lightgreen;
}


 .contact-info h4 {
    font-family: "Arial Black";
    font-weight: bolder;
}


.contact-icon {
    padding-top: 50px;
}

.contact-block {
    padding-top: 20px;
    align-content: center;
    margin-left: 5%;
}

.aboutme h1 {
    padding-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    font-family: "Arial Black";
    font-size: 50px;
    color: black;
    font-weight: bolder;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px darkgray;
}

.my-contact .contact-info {
    display: table-cell;
    font-size: 18px;

}

.my-contact .contact-icon span {
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 25px;
}

.contact-summary  {
    padding-top: 70px;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 20px;
}


.contact-developer {
    padding-top: 95px;
    margin-bottom: 7%;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

/********************Contact*********************/
```

```html
<!----------------------Intro-------------------------------->


<section id="intro-section" class="intro">
    <div class="intro-content">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                    <h1>HELLO, I'M ERIC.</h1>
                    <div id="typed-strings">
                        <p>Welcome to my personal website!</p>
                        <p>UI DESIGNER / WEB DEVELOPER</p>
                    </div>
                    <span id="typed"></span>
                    <div class="button">
                        <button>GET IN TOUCH</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<!----------------------Intro----------------------------->

<!----------------------Contact----------------------------->
<section id="about" class="aboutme">
    <h1>ABOUT ME</h1>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="contact-block clearfix">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
                        <div class="contact-summary">
                            <p>Welcome to my personal website! My name is Eric Holdridge. I'm a web developer and UI designer. I have been web developing for 2 years.
                                I love creating beautiful and responsive websites for anyone. Most web designers won't put in the time and effort to create a
                                fully functional website. If you have an idea, I will make it happen. You can reach me at
                                one of my contact options below.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                    <div class="my-contact clearfix">
                        <div class="contact-icon">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
                            <div class="contact-info">
                                <h4>Name:</h4>
                                <p>Eric</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                    <div class="my-contact clearfix">
                        <div class="contact-icon">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>
                            <div class="contact-info">
                                <h4>Email:</h4>
                                <p>e@gmail.com</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                    <div class="my-contact clearfix">
                        <div class="contact-icon">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone"></span>
                            <div class="contact-info">
                                <h4>Phone:</h4>
                                <p>(563)</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                    <div class="my-contact clearfix">
                        <div class="contact-icon">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                            <div class="contact-info">
                                <h4>Date of Birth:</h4>
                                <p>April</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                    <div class="my-contact clearfix">
                        <div class="contact-icon">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></span>
                            <div class="contact-info">
                                <h4>Location:</h4>
                                <p></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                    <div class="my-contact clearfix">
                        <div class="contact-icon">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-flag"></span>
                            <div class="contact-info">
                                <h4>Nationality:</h4>
                                <p>United States</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
                        <div class="contact-developer">
                            <p>CREATIVE FRONT-END AND BACK-END DEVELOPER.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>


<!----------------------Contact----------------------------->
```

Comment: Would be easier to add another div inside section and add a padding around that. You will not have to give your h1's any margin or padding.

Comment: @Syfer you can disable the `margin-top` and just use `padding-top` on the `h1` instead if you want space there. `padding` doesn't collapse like `margin`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's the margin on your `h1`'s collapsing outside of the parent. There are a bunch of ways to fix it, so I just removed the top margin on `h1`.

Here's a resource - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing

> If there is no border, padding, inline content, block_formatting_context created or clearance to separate the margin-top of a block from the margin-top of its first child block, or no border, padding, inline content, height, min-height, or max-height to separate the margin-bottom of a block from the margin-bottom of its last child, then those margins collapse. The collapsed margin ends up outside the parent.

```css
/********************Intro**********************/

.intro-content {
    padding-top:  250px;
}

.intro-content h1 {
    font-family: "Arial Black";
    font-weight: bolder;
}

#typed {
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.button {
    padding-top: 50px;
}

.button button {
    background-color: black;
    border-color: black;
    border-radius: 25px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bolder;
    margin-bottom: 22%;
}



/********************Intro*********************/



/********************Contact*********************/

#about {
    background-color: lightgray;
}

#skill {
    background-color: lightblue;
}

#intro-section {
    background-color: lightgreen;
}


 .contact-info h4 {
    font-family: "Arial Black";
    font-weight: bolder;
}


.contact-icon {
    padding-top: 50px;
}

.contact-block {
    padding-top: 20px;
    align-content: center;
    margin-left: 5%;
}

.aboutme h1 {
    padding-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    font-family: "Arial Black";
    font-size: 50px;
    color: black;
    font-weight: bolder;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px darkgray;
}

.my-contact .contact-info {
    display: table-cell;
    font-size: 18px;

}

.my-contact .contact-icon span {
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 25px;
}

.contact-summary  {
    padding-top: 70px;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 20px;
}


.contact-developer {
    padding-top: 95px;
    margin-bottom: 7%;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

/********************Contact*********************/

h1 {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<!----------------------Intro-------------------------------->


<section id="intro-section" class="intro">
    <div class="intro-content">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                    <h1>HELLO, I'M ERIC.</h1>
                    <div id="typed-strings">
                        <p>Welcome to my personal website!</p>
                        <p>UI DESIGNER / WEB DEVELOPER</p>
                    </div>
                    <span id="typed"></span>
                    <div class="button">
                        <button>GET IN TOUCH</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<!----------------------Intro----------------------------->

<!----------------------Contact----------------------------->
<section id="about" class="aboutme">
    <h1>ABOUT ME</h1>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="contact-block clearfix">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
                        <div class="contact-summary">
                            <p>Welcome to my personal website! My name is Eric Holdridge. I'm a web developer and UI designer. I have been web developing for 2 years.
                                I love creating beautiful and responsive websites for anyone. Most web designers won't put in the time and effort to create a
                                fully functional website. If you have an idea, I will make it happen. You can reach me at
                                one of my contact options below.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                    <div class="my-contact clearfix">
                        <div class="contact-icon">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
                            <div class="contact-info">
                                <h4>Name:</h4>
                                <p>Eric</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                    <div class="my-contact clearfix">
                        <div class="contact-icon">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>
                            <div class="contact-info">
                                <h4>Email:</h4>
                                <p>e@gmail.com</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                    <div class="my-contact clearfix">
                        <div class="contact-icon">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone"></span>
                            <div class="contact-info">
                                <h4>Phone:</h4>
                                <p>(563)</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                    <div class="my-contact clearfix">
                        <div class="contact-icon">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                            <div class="contact-info">
                                <h4>Date of Birth:</h4>
                                <p>April</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                    <div class="my-contact clearfix">
                        <div class="contact-icon">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></span>
                            <div class="contact-info">
                                <h4>Location:</h4>
                                <p></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                    <div class="my-contact clearfix">
                        <div class="contact-icon">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-flag"></span>
                            <div class="contact-info">
                                <h4>Nationality:</h4>
                                <p>United States</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
                        <div class="contact-developer">
                            <p>CREATIVE FRONT-END AND BACK-END DEVELOPER.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>


<!----------------------Contact----------------------------->
```